# Opencv Python :need more than 2 values to unpack

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm writing an opencv program and i found this error
When i run the code this is the answer i get

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):`File "Imagesegmentation.py", line 29, in <module>
image,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

my code is

```
import cv2
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from skimage.feature import hog
import numpy as np
import argparse as ap


parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
#parser.add_argument("-c", "--classiferPath", help="Path to Classifier File", required="True")
parser.add_argument("-i", "--image", help="Path to Image")

args = vars(parser.parse_args())

im = cv2.imread("/home/user/Desktop/python/New Doc 2018-02-12_1.jpg")

im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

im_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_gray, (15, 15), 0)

ret, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

cv2.namedWindow("Image grayscale", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow("Image grayscale", im_th)

cv2.waitKey()

_,ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 

cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

rects = [None]*100

ctrCount=0

for ctr in ctrs:

    if cv2.contourArea(ctr) >= 500:
        rects[ctrCount] = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
        ctrCount=ctrCount+1

print 'ctrCount = ', ctrCount

newImageCount = 0

for rect in rects:

    cv2.rectangle(im, (rect[0], rect[1]), (rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1] + rect[3]), (0, 255, 0), 3) 

    leng = int(rect[3] * 1.6)
    pt1 = int(rect[1] + rect[3] // 2 - leng // 2)
    pt2 = int(rect[0] + rect[2] // 2 - leng // 2)
    roi = im_th[pt1:pt1+leng, pt2:pt2+leng]


    try:
        roi = cv2.resize(roi, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        #roi = cv2.dilate(roi, (3, 3))

        name = 'image'+str(newImageCount)+'.jpg'
        cv2.imwrite(name, roi)
        newImageCount = newImageCount+1
        #cv2.namedWindow("ROIs", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        #cv2.imshow("ROIs", roi)
        #cv2.waitKey()
    except:
        print 'Error'

cv2.namedWindow("Resulting Image with Rectangular ROIs", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow("Resulting Image with Rectangular ROIs", im)

cv2.waitKey()
```

any help?

Comment: Probably the call in line 29 is not returning 3 values. Perhaps the output is different depending on the value of the mode and/or method arguments.

Comment: Which is the version of `opencv` ?

Comment: Documentation about opencv has an example that shows 3 values as return value: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a

Just a guess: Maybe an earlier version of opencv has a different return value? The documentation for version "2.x" is not clear about it

Comment: @FlorianM. I version "2.x" it will only return 2 values.

Comment: @RahulKP Thanks. And from the import "import cv2" we can imagine, it's version 2.x ....

Comment: Unfortunately version 3 import is also `import cv2`. If you are not dealing with video input I recommend skimage instead of opencv - opencv does not feel like Python.

Comment: Opencv 2.4.13.5

Answer (score 1):

While you are using `Opencv 2.4.13.5` ,

`cv2.findContours` only return 2 values. So you need to change like this.

```
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Or you can upgrade to `Opencv 3.x`,

[reference](http://answers.opencv.org/question/32248/open-cv-30-findcontours-return-too-many-value-to-unpack/)